# Собирательные числительные

Tags: количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

*За прошедшие выходные в крымской горно-лесной зоне спасатели оказали помощь трем туристкам, двое из которых получили травмы.* Меня интересуют числительные: правильно ли употребление?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За прошедшие выходные в крымской горно-лесной зоне спасатели оказали помощь трем туристкам, **две** из которых получили травмы.

Собирательные числительные **не сочетаются** с сущ. женского рода.